# bcp query out XML file format issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

These xml are not my friend. Currently I have a table that contains xml files that I need to query out to a folder.

The XML data when viewed in SQL looks like the following[image]

When I use the following code I get a different output:

```
   SET @CommandOUt = '
bcp "select XMLDATA from [INTELLECTION].[dbo].[XMLwithOpenXMLout] row WHERE ID = '+@Hist_ID+' for xml auto, root(), elements" ' +
'queryout "D:\New folder\' + @Hist_ID+'.xml" -S INTEL-SQL01\OUTSOURCECAPTURE -T -w -r -t' 



 EXEC xp_cmdshell   @CommandOUT
```

Output :
[image]

The required out should not have "rows"row"XMLDATA"

It should be like below:[image]

How do I correct my BCP query out to get the correct output?

Comment: It's already an XML column. Have you tried not `for xml`-ing it?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with bcp. You need to run your `SELECT XMLDATA from...` statement in SSMS on its own, and make sure it producing exactly what you need.